# How can we delete firebase user if he doesn't verify email?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to delete user from firebase authentication and also want to delete data from real-time database   if the user doesn't verify email address with in 1 hours. Deleting a user is easy but if doesn't verify in 1  hour then how could I do this? The problem is that firebase is server less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write and deploy a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that periodically:

1. Queries your database for users who have not verified (you will need a child to record that).
2. Delete the database record and also [delete the user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

You will need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) for both of these steps.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy! just create a real-time database of the unverified user database. and when the user signup the time will be also registered in the database. So when the apps start it check the unverified users and there you write the if-else statement if the difference between time is greater than 1hour the user will be deleted.

It's so simple as I said :)

Answer (score 0):

**Run `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()` function inside `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function to see if user is verified or not. if user is verfied then only create users database otherwise give an exception and break the function, it won't save unverified users data.**

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email,Pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
               
                if (task.isSuccessful()){

                    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()){
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Uid = user.getUid();

                        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

                        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasChild(Uid)){
                                    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Uid);

                                    HashMap<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
                                    userMap.put("Name","default");
                                    userMap.put("email",Email);
                                   

                                    databaseReference.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                        //call your function here when user sign in first time after email verification
                                           
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });

                        //call your function when user already registered and verified
                        //and already saved his information to database

                    }else{
                        //show your exception here
                    }
                }else{
                    //show your exception here
                }
            }
        });
```