# how to remove user from Firebase Authentication if email is not verified

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

in my app i use Firebase (Email/password) authentication and i verify user email by sending link to user, using auth.currUser.sendEmailVerification()

my question is i want to remove user from Firebase authentication if user don't verify email in any case
(user is Authenticated and saved in Firebase Authentication but not verified)

Comment: in fire base they have already process to confirm by phone or email verification .. I don't think, you need to do remove anyone manually..

Comment: i am saving user in my database if user email is verified

Comment: Have you checked [how can we delete Firebase user if email is not verified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64468970/13130697) and other linked answers? You can periodically delete users with unverified email that way.

Comment: its means without verifying you are saving user in Sqlite or firbase database??